# How can I get Firefox to display MIME types in-browser?

Tags: firefox

When I click on a *.json or *.patch file in Firefox, it asks me what external application I want to view it in.

However, I don't *want* to use an external application. It's plain text -- I just want to view it in-browser.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the UI for this.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an add-on that might help: ["Open in browser"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207)

And here's a KB article that also might help, ["MimeTypes"](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf)

Comment: I'd like to register my own mime type / file extension. I read both of those pages and it looks like they say if I really want to I can modify (hack) the mimeTypes file but I'd like to register it the way other mime types are registered. Do you know if I have to install a desktop application or browser plugin to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

In general you should use the `"tools->options->applications"` to edit which application is used by default to open different mime types.  However if you can't set it that way you can edit the [mimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) directly, but this is discouraged.

Adding the following should work (use at your own risk):

```
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:application/json"
           NC:value="application/json"
           NC:path="<path to firefox>"
           NC:saveToDisk="false"
           NC:editable="true"
           NC:prettyName="JSON object">
<NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/json"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing+file+types

If you open the preferences windows and go to the Applications tab, you should be able to find the content type (application/json) and change its action to "Use Firefox"

Comment: Nope. You can do that for, say, "HTML document", but for some reason the option isn't there for arbitrary types like JSON.